# Parse Json in Logic App from Stream Analytics -> Service Hub -> Logic Apps

Tags: json, azureservicebus, azure-stream-analytics, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to build a logic app that inserts data into a Sql database. The data is coming from s Stream Analytics job, outputting it on a Service Bus topic, consumed in Logic Apps in Service Bus trigger.

To populate the properties of the row inserted (lets say it only has one column 'Name'), I've found that this should work using following syntax:

```
 "body": {
          "Name": "@{json(decodeBase64(triggerBody()['ContentData'])).Name}"
  },
```

Provided the message body contains a 'Name' property.

However I get following error message when running this:

> {"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Insert_row' inputs at line '1' and column '2017': 'The template language function 'json' parameter is not valid. The provided value '@\u0006string\b3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/��{\"time\":\"2016-05-25T10:29:17.4953250Z\",\"Name\":\"Y-Axis\",\"Value\":81.0,\"Date\":\"2016-05-25T10:29:17.4953250\",\"EventProcessedUtcTime\":\"2016-05-25T10:29:17.5525449Z\",\"PartitionId\":2,\"EventEnqueuedUtcTime\":\"2016-05-25T10:29:17.2220000Z\"}\u0001' cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: @. Path '', line 0, position 0.'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#json for usage details.'."}

So it seems like that the content is enclosed in another envelope that is preventing json parsing to work.

1) Any simple way how to get around this?

2) Isn't such an integration all within Microsoft Stack just supposed to work without this mocking around?

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Did you get this working in a non hacky way?

Answer (score 3):

with the limited string functions available in he workflow definition language I had to use a long winded way for removing the additional strings

```
@{json(substring(replace(decodeBase64(triggerBody()['ContentData']),'@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/��', ''),0,sub(length(replace(decodeBase64(triggerBody()['ContentData']),'@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/��', '')),1))).fieldname}
```

is there a better way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this, you're right it should simply work. There is a known issue where ASA ServiceBus output JSON is being wrapped in a XML header. It will be addressed in a near future but can't specify a particular date. Could you please workaround it (maybe using substring/replace) until then ?

cheers,
Chetan

Comment: The issue is fixed, look at the other answer below on how to enable it for your job.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay in getting back, this issue is now fixed. Its exposed under a new compatibility level (1.1) to avoid breaking existing solutions. Please use this [URL](https://ms.portal.azure.com/?feature.canmodifyextensions=true&Microsoft_Azure_StreamAnalytics_compatibility=true) to configure your job with compat level 1.1 and give it a try.

cheers!

Comment: I create my ASA instances via the PowerShell Cmdlet, how do I set a "compatibility level 1.1" from there ?

Comment: I have contacted Microsoft about this, and there are some issues with this solution. This "Compatability Mode" is still in preview and it includes a few other changes to the behaviour of SA, and further changes are possible before GA. Regarding my original comment, supposedly adding "compatibilityLevel" : 1.1 , to the ARM template should work, didn't test it out because of the other issues.

Comment: I tested setting the compatibility level in the ARM template and it does work. You have to add the property to the resource's "properties" object - adjacent to the inputs and outputs arrays:

"properties": {
          ...
          "outputErrorPolicy": "stop",
          "eventsOutOfOrderPolicy": "adjust",
          "eventsOutOfOrderMaxDelayInSeconds": 0,
          "eventsLateArrivalMaxDelayInSeconds": 5,
          "dataLocale": "en-US",
          "compatibilityLevel" : "1.1",
          "inputs": [
          ....
Azure Resource Explorer (https://resources.azure.com/) really helped!